# What is the correct way to denote empty n-ary intersection of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, index-notation

I'm trying to prove the statement:

> Show that a finite intersection of open subsets in a metric space is open.

If I'm able to enumerate the sets as $U_1, \ldots, U_n$ and consider $U := \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n U_i$, I have no problem writing the proof. But "finite" can also mean empty, so by listing the sets out like this, I think I'm sacrificing generality. What I'm really doing is defining $U := \bigcap\limits_{i \in I_n} U_i$, where $I_n$ is an indexing set of size $n \geq 0$. If $n = 0$, $U = X$ by definition, which is open. But the notation $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n U_i$ doesn't make sense in the case where $n = 0$, unless $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^0 U_i$ means "empty intersection."

Is there a way to get around this subtlety?

Comment: You can say $\cap_{i=1}^0U_i=\emptyset$ because $x\in\cap_{i=1}^0U_i$ iff there exists $i$ such that $x\in U_i$ and $1\le i\le 0.$.... There are many times where the empty set is an obvious special case and where it is awkward to present a proof without treating some special case separately.

Comment: The intersection of no sets is $X$, the whole space (for all $x$ it holds trivially that $\forall 1 \le i \le 0: x \in U_i$ because there *are* no such $i$; it's a universal quantor over an empty domain....)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That is a definition of union, not intersection. For intersection you would have "for all" instead of "there exists", and then it's vacuously true for all x.

Comment: The property you are trying to prove is usually taken as a defining property of openness, so it would have helped to specify which definition of openness you are working with… if your problem had been about openness at all. Because what it *actually* seems to be about is just proper notation for the degenerate case of n-ary intersection. Meanwhile, answerers are stuck trying to how to prove this property of openness while ignoring your actual problem. So maybe you should remove the mention of openness from the title and de-emphasise it in the body.

Comment: You say "unless" $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^0 U_i$ means empty intersection, i.e. the entire space $X$. But you should just say that you *define* it to mean just that. It is in no conflict with any other definition, and everyone should agree that **if** you allowed $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^0 U_i$ to be defined, then it must be defined to be $X$.

Answer (score 3):

To prove that all finite intersections of open sets are open it is necessary and sufficient that "$U,V$ open implies $U \cap V$" open. You don't need a "general case" at all. It follow by induction on general principles. This yields the simplest proof IMO. If you insist you can note that the empty intersection is just $X$ (the whole space) by common logical convention (and this is open anyway) and a one-set intersection is just the set itself (so a set is open if a set is open, a tautology). Just do the binary case and that's the only relevant one.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give a full proof.

Take two open sets $U$ and $V$ .

Consider the set $U\cap V$.

Let $x\in U\cap V$.

Then as $x\in U\,\exists\,r_{1}>0$ such that $B(x,r_{1}(x))\subset U$. and correspondingly $r_{2}>0$ such that $B(x,r_{2})\subset V$.

Take $r_{0}(x)=\frac{\min(r_{1}(x),r_{2}(x))}{2}$. So You have $B(x,r_{0})\subset B(x,r_{1})\subset  U$ and

$B(x,r_{0})\subset B(x,r_{2})\subset V$.

So $B(x,r_{0}(x))\subset U\cap V$.

Thus $\displaystyle U\cap V=\bigcup_{x\in U\cap V} B(x,r_{0}(x))$ is open as it is union of open balls.

Now that you have intersection of two sets is open. you can extend it for finitely many using induction.

for example $U_{1}\cap U_{2}\cap U_{3}$ is open as $(U_{1}\cap U_{2})=U_{0}$ is open and hence $U_{0}\cap U_{3}$ is also open.

Now the only degenerate case is when the intersection is empty
. In that case it is open as the null set is always open by definition of topology. If the intersection is non-empty we proceed like I did above.

Answer (score 1):

The empty set is an open set so that does not pose a problem. In fact you can begin by saying if the intersection is empty then we are done. Then let $x$ be a point in the intersection. Since $x$ is in each of the $U_i$ and each of the $U_i$ are open there exists $\epsilon_1, ..., \epsilon_n$ such that $B_{\epsilon_i}(x)\subset U_i$. Take the minimum of the $\epsilon_i$ to get that $B_{\text{min}(\epsilon_i)}(x)$ is a subset of the intersection.

Comment: I'm ok with the intersection being empty because then the quantification I need to show is vacuously true; the only issue I have is the indexing set being empty. This is indeed the proof I had in mind when $I$ isn't empty, though.

Comment: You don't have to worry about an empty indexing set. The theorem only asserts that a finite intersection of open sets is open. You don't have to reference an indexing set at all.

Comment: But doesn't finite mean of size $n \geq 0$, i.e., empty or in bijection with $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ for some $n \geq 1$? That's my confusion.

Comment: If the size is zero, then there isn't an intersection. I wouldn't even bother with the case that $n=1$ because the general proof takes that into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have $U = \bigcap_{j=a}^b U_j$ defined as:

$$ \forall x: [x \in U \iff x \in X \land \forall j \in \mathbb{Z} : \underbrace{a \le j \land j \le b \Rightarrow x \in U_j}_{(*)}] $$

If you set $a = 1$ and $b = 0$, the implication (*) becomes [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) for all $x \in X$ and $j \in \mathbb{Z}$.  The condition $1 \le j \land j \le 0$ may look silly, but it’s a perfectly well-formed logical formula; it just happens to be always false.  As such, $\bigcap_{j=1}^0 U_j$ is likewise perfectly well-defined as the whole space $X$.

One could take the awkwardness of this notation as an argument for using [zero-based indexing and half-open intervals](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) even in non-CS mathematics.  While I am personally quite sympathetic to the idea, good luck convincing your fellow mathematicians to accept your alternative definition of $\bigcap_{j=a}^b$ where the upper bound is excluded.  The practice is just too entrenched.<sup>0</sup>

If it really bothers you, a more practical option would be to give up the $\bigcap_{j=a}^b$ notation, and instead come up with a succinct enough notation for the interval $[0, n) \cap \mathbb {Z}$ (the von Neumann ordinal of $n$); it is common to use $[n]$ for a set like this.  Then you can use $\bigcap_{j \in [n]}$ everywhere instead.

---

<sup>0</sup> Well, other than in notations like $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j$, which somehow *don’t* include $a_\infty$ as the last summand.

Comment: I think this nicely addresses the concern: *"But the notation $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n U_i$ doesn't make sense in the case where $n = 0$"*

Answer (score -1):

Even if you have one set, there is no "intersection". There has to be at least two sets and this is understood when you interpret the "intersection" part.

Comment: The way that "intersection" is defined in basic set theory (at least all the versions I've seen) will work just fine if you are intersecting a collection that contains just one set.